# Combining regex groups to one group or exlude a character from a match

Tags: regex

I have this string, and I need to get the datetime out of it by using regex. I have little to no experience with regex and am stuck.

As an example, take this string: Vic-nc_20150406_0100

I want to get the following result: 201504060100

How am I to accomplish this? So far I've come up with this expression: `([0-9]{8})_([0-9]{4})`, although the result is two groups (20150404 and 0100).
Another expression I've come up with is `([0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4})`, now the result is 20150406_0100.

I either need to combine the groups or filter out the [_] somehow. Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to do replace. Which lang/tool  you are running?

Comment: You can have a look at this: https://regex101.com/r/bG7qX6/3. Result: `201504060100`.

Comment: Hmm replace does work, the problem is that I am using an API, and I cannot change the code. I need to specify a regex in an XML configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace, then just take the value of two groups.

Find `(\d{8})_(\d{4})`
Replace `\1\2` or `$1$2` based on your program language.